# how can you ensure proper javascript detection when a web users visits a webpage?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

on a standard web page, how can you get JavaScript to accurately detect when a user is visiting given the user may be on eastern, central, western or any other time zone while browsing to the web page?

in other words, how can I use JavaScript to detect the current date time of a users page load is between two specific date/times while not knowing what time zone the user's browser is actually set to?

I want to display a message between Friday March 4th 2014 noon until Saturday March 5th 7AM **EASTERN** time to users who brose my site. How can I ensure this logic not knowing what the browser's time zone is set to locally on their machines?

Is there a universal way in JavaScript of date time comparisons like SQL server has using UTC?

Comment: Usually you would base this type of thing off of server-time, not client time. client-time can't be trusted.

Comment: i don’t have that luxury here and need a JavaScript only solution. isn’t there a browser property java script can use? locale?

Comment: You can use the UTC methods found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date